# How can I dynamically resize a div to fill the height of the page but be aware of the sticky footer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm sure this will get downvoted for the lack of HTML but I'm really just looking for an answer on whether or not it can be done.

Basically I'm using a slideshow plugin which sizes itself on whatever the size of the div is and I need that div to dynamically set its height according to the size of the page.

[image: Example Image of what I need.]

Comment: Please show what you tried as well as explain behavior expectations with regard to aspect ratios

Answer (score 1):

Try this; [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/tmprmr3d/)

```
// HTML
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" style="background-color:red;height:20px;">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="background-color:blue;height:20px;">
    </div>
</div>

// CSS
* { width: 100%; margin: 0px; }
#wrapper { height: 100%; }
#header { position: absolute; top:0; }
#content { position: relative; padding: 20px 0px; }
#footer { position: absolute; bottom:0; }
```

Comment: The `#content` will be below the header with this code, and please don't place css in the html, only if it's _really_ necessary.

Comment: Inline CSS was purely because it wasn't necessary in the code if the header and footer had content, and color was just to make it more visible. You are of course right about the content below header `#content{ padding: 20px 0px; }` fixes this problem.

Answer (score -1):

By sticky footer I am assuming that you mean `position:fixed`.  Yes, this can be done.  All you have to do is make the `div` responsive by specifying its `height` as a percentage; like `height: 80%`.

To get that to work, however, the `div`'s parent container needs to have its `height` property set as well.  For example you could do

```
body 
{
    height: 100%;
}

.responsiveDiv
{
    height: 80%;
}
```

And simply

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="responsiveDiv">Slideshow stuff</div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

And of course you would have to set the height of the `header` and `footer` appropriately to make sure nothing overlaps.

Comment: But if the header and footer have a fixed height in pixels, I would use the `calc` function. Subtract the sum of header height and footer height from 100vh;
`.responsiveDiv { height: calc(100vh - 200px); }`.
** Edit: ** By the way, I think OP would need to use the `!important` flag on the height, because I assume the plugin would place an inline style attribute.

Comment: @shirfy I never said that the header and footer should be a fixed height in pixels.  I should've stated that the header + footer + div should equal 100%.

Comment: I wrote that for the OP so he would know there's this option too, many people still don't know about `calc`. Our designer in the company likes to create the height of headers, footers and such in pixels and the rest between are responsive. It was just my 2 cents. Cheers.